# How to transfer data for survival analysis

Tags: survival-analysis

I'm trying to set up my data for survival analysis using R. I have four variables T1, T2, T3, T4 each representing a time point where the participants were evaluated. Code 1 and 2 mean that they did not pass the test; code 0 means that they passed the test. I'm trying to transfer this information into two new variables: time (the number of intervals they took to pass the test) and event (whether they passed the test). I'm really new to R and would appreciate any insights regarding how to set up my data! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is named `df`.

- `time` is defined as the first instance when code 0 is observed.
- If code 0 is never observed time stops at T4 (4).
- If `time` is less than 4, it implies `Pass`.
- If `time` is 4 and T4 is 0, it implies `Pass`.
- If `time` is 4 and T4 is not 0, it implies `Fail`.

```
library(dplyr) # For mutate() and case_when() functions
library(magrittr) # For %<>% pipe, instead of doing df <- df %>% ...

df %<>% mutate(time = case_when(T1 == 0 ~ 1, 
                                T2 == 0 ~ 2, 
                                T3 == 0 ~ 3, 
                                T4 == 0 ~ 4, 
                                TRUE ~ 4), 
               event = case_when(time < 4 ~ "Pass", 
                                 time == 4 & T4 == 0 ~ "Pass", 
                                 TRUE ~ "Fail"))
```